# Kentico 8 - Redirect to user culture version from a *.com

Tags: c#, kentico

I've setup a website in kentico to use a unique *.com domain with url prefixes (*.com/fr-fr/, *.com/fr-be/, *.com/nl-be/)

what I'd like to do now is to redirect the user that access the site domain.com to the related culture based on user language, using fr-fr as default.

is it possible to configure kentico to do so or do I need to add custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration Kentico for anonymous visitors

You can configure the default content culture that the website displays to anonymous visitors. This can be done separately for the main website domain and for individual domain aliases:

```
Sites -> edit a site -> General -> Visitor culture - used for visitors accessing the website through a URL containing the main domain name.
Sites -> edit a site -> Domain Aliases -> edit an alias -> Visitor culture - used for visitors accessing the website through a URL that contains the domain alias.
```

The values can either be set to one of the cultures available for the website, or to (Automatic), in which case the user's browser settings are used (for example, in Internet Explorer, you can set the default language in Tools -> Internet options -> General -> Languages).

More Info:
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Setting+default+languages+for+users+and+visitors

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right - go to *Sites* > edit your site > *Domain aliases* tab > create desired one > set Redirect URL, and Default alias path for visitor culture. You can find more info [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Setting+default+languages+for+users+and+visitors).